# How to encode custom multitrack surround WAV in LogicPro9 or Reaper?

Tags: poly-wav, custom, surround-sound

Hi!

How to encode 8 mono tracks into one 8-channeled WAV mix (poly wav?)

Actually, there are no surround system in the customers project, just 8 speakers, placed linearly. And I need to mix two stereo tracks into 8ch for proper playing, because of unusual sound setup/soft.

Tried with Logic 9 7.1 SDDS, but it seems to be bad way.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

"but it seems to be bad way." could you clarify?

[This might help you](https://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/9.1.6/en/logicpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=39%26section=1%26tasks=true). Note that the only difference in discrete WAVs is [the channel order](https://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/9.1.6/en/logicpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=39%26section=2). Other than that, they are ordinary multichannel WAVs, only with more than 2 ch.

However:

> Note: The surround format chosen here only alters the layout/routing of channels to speakers in the assignment section. The actual project surround format is determined by the Surround Format setting in Audio project settings

[image: logic channel order configuration]

I guess your best bet is to figure out what the channel order on your system is, then adjust your chosen 7.1 format accordingly.

Comment: georgi, thank you for answer!

"but it seems to be bad way." - I meant loosing 1 mono track in the bounced surround 7.1 mix. May be it was LFE ch. and Logic automatically filtered all freq. above 125Hz...

Some update: I achieved my goal with Reaper, but resulting multichannel WAV doesn't play. And there is only 1 difference between playable WAV and "corrupt" - last one has no media info about channels, whereas ok version does consist info like "L - Lc - C - Rc..."

Here are these 2 WAVes:
correct - http://goo.gl/yAy13
corrupt - http://goo.gl/W5tKy





Comment: Center and LFE are separate sliders on Logic's surround panner... I assume you've checked them?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to georgi answer, you could use [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) software.

Audacity has an option (in import/export preferences, check 'use personal mix' instead of 'always reduce to stereo') that allow the assign specific tracks to the resulting wav export.

The basic use would be :

- import each of your eight mono wav files into it's respective track in
  an audacity project.
- File > Export > wav should then open a window where you can assign
  each of the project track to a channel in the output poly wav.